# How do I copy a slice of a matrix and paste it to the end of the same matrix in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, copy

I have a matrix of size `(21, 15, 50)` and I want to take the last level of the matrix which would be a size `(1, 15, 50)` and I want to copy that matrix slice and paste it back to the original so then the original matrix would have a size of `(22, 15, 50)`. This would result in slices 21 and 22 to have the same values.

I have tried `np.hstack()` and `append()` but I could be using them incorrectly.

What is the syntax for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call your 3d array is `a`.

This code may solve your problem:

```
a = np.concatenate((a, a[-1,:,:].reshape(1,15,50)), axis=0)
```

I have tried and checked the shape of a, the result is `(22,15,50)` as you want.